# Can't fetch slack user profile information with API

Tags: python, slack

Thank you so much in advance. I am trying to fetch user profile information through `slack_authentication`. Although the app is successfully authenticated with Slack, it could not get **email** and **username**.

> {'ok': True, 'access_token': 'xoxp-xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'scope': 'identify,channels:read,users.profile:read,chat:write:bot,identity.basic', 'user_id': 'XXXXXXXXX', 'team_id': 'XXXXXXXX', 'enterprise_id': None, 'team_name': 'test', 'warning': 'superfluous_charset', 'response_metadata': {'warnings': ['superfluous_charset']}}

I tried to add `identify` scope instead of `identity.basic` because slack doesn't allow you to use both `identity.basic` and other scopes.

The code is below:

```
@bp.route('/redirect', methods=['GET'])
def authorize():
    authorize_url = f"https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope={ oauth_scope }&client_id={ client_id }"

    return authorize_url

@bp.route('/callback', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def callback():
    auth_code = request.args['code']
    client = slack.WebClient(token="")
    response = client.oauth_access(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        code=auth_code
    )
    print(response)
```

### Additional

I have realized how to get `users info`. I updated the code to like this.

The code is updated like below:

```
    oauth = client.oauth_access(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        code=auth_code
    )
    user_id = oauth['user_id']
    response = client.users_info(user=user_id)
```

But this error occurs:

> The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'not_authed'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like an installation routine for a Slack app using OAuth. But it does not contain a call to get a user profile.

To get the profile of a user you can call [`users.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) and provide the ID of the user you are interested in.

Examples:

```
response = client.users_info(user=ID_OF_USER)
assert(response)
profile = response['user']['profile']
email = response['user']['profile']['email']
```

In order to retrieve the user's profile and email address you need these scopes:
 - users:read
 - users:read.email

The identity scopes are unrelated to the user profile. They are used for the "[Sign-in with Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack)" approach only, where you can authenticate with a Slack user on a 3rd party web site.

Finally, just to clarify, because this is often misunderstood: You only need to run through the OAuth installation routine once. The routine will yield you a token for the workspace, which you can store and use for any further calls to the API for that workspace.

### Update to "Additional"

You are not using the API correctly.

You need to first complete the Oauth flow and collect the access token, which is in the response from `client.oauth_access`.

Then you need to initialize a new WebClient with the token you received. With the new client you can then access all API methods, like users.info etc.

Again: You should run through the OAuth process one time only and store the received token for later use.

Example:

```
oauth_info = client.oauth_access(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    code=auth_code
)
access_token = oauth_info['access_token'] # you want to store this token in a database

client = slack.WebClient(token=access_token)
user_id = oauth_info['user_id']
response = client.users_info(user=user_id)
print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I make sense. By the way, how can I get ID_OF_USER? I tried to use `user_id` getting from oauth_access but it didn't work...

Comment: user ID from OAuth should work. What error are you getting from the API? Also, check this out for details on how to get IDs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940327/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-find-a-slack-team-id-and-a-channel-id/44883343#44883343

Comment: Much appreciated for your additional pointing out. I have updated a question.

Comment: Completely I got it! Thank you so much :)