# Get Slack userId in AWS lex Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have integrated my AWS Lex bot in slack. I want to get the userId from slack

```
userId = intent_request['userId']
```

Here the userID comes in `{channelID}:{SlackTeamID}:{SlackUserID}` format.

How to get the SlackUserID from this.

Comment: see this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940327/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-find-a-slack-team-id-and-a-channel-id

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the session id which lex post to lambda will have session id. It contains the slack user id information. You can take that info and query Slack API to get user info.
Hope this help.